# Implement a circuit with a decoder

Tags: decoder

I'm solving previous' years exams problems and i'm having trouble understanding one part of the problem. So I solve the first part and I have the truth table which is:

[image: two muppets]
I did elimination with Karnaugh and I've got that output D is (A'B + C). Now, the second part says that I've got decoders of all combinations and OR chips. It wants me to implement the circuit with the simplest possible way.

Now, I know that with decoders I can implement all circuits and when I've got functions in format of sums (Σ1,2,3,5,7 in this case) I can use a decoder but I've got only one output function and all the exercises i've seen have 2+ outputs. What do i do? I create one 3x8 Decoder and a 5-input OR gate?

Answer (score 1):

what if you make C one of the inputs to the or gate?

> how about (A'B) in an encoder and a 2 input or gate to combine C

Comment: So what would be the final circuit? Is this considered the simplest implementation?

Comment: just a two input encoder with the A'B output going into a 2 input or gate combining that with C. I can't immagine anything having fewer parts or wires.